# Why am I getting deprecated function warnings?

Tags: drupal, error, pcp

When I run updates (such as with an updated module) in Drupal (7.87), I get the following CiviCRM (5.46.2) related warning:

*User deprecated function: Deprecated function CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::pcpStatus, use Function pcpStatus will be removed. in CRM_Core_Error::deprecatedFunctionWarning() (line 1044 of /home/example/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php).*

These warnings are not specific to this version of CiviCRM; they have been going on for a while. I just kept hoping the next version of CiviCRM would correct it.

I believe the pcp refers to Personal Campaign Pages, but I may be wrong. My site does not have any of those.

Any thoughts welcomed :-)

---

BACKTRACE OUTPUT per comments:

Mar 01 14:19:08  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(1038): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

#1 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/PseudoConstant.php(352): CRM_Core_Error::deprecatedFunctionWarning("Function pcpStatus will be removed")

#2 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/civicrm/civicrm_handler_filter_pseudo_constant.inc(45): CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::pcpStatus()

#3 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/views/includes/handlers.inc(65): civicrm_handler_filter_pseudo_constant->construct()

#4 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/views/includes/handlers.inc(87): _views_create_handler((Array:8), "handler", "filter")

#5 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/views/views.module(1399): _views_prepare_handler((Array:8), (Array:18), "status", "filter")

#6 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/date/date_views/includes/date_views_fields.inc(59): views_get_handler("civicrm_pcp", "status", "filter")

#7 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/date/date_views/date_views.module(156): _date_views_fields("civicrm_contact")

#8 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar.views_template.inc(37): date_views_fields("civicrm_contact")

#9 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/views/views.module(1520): calendar_views_templates()

#10 /home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/views/views_ui.module(56): views_get_all_templates()

#11 /home/XXXX/www/www/includes/menu.inc(2831): views_ui_menu()

#12 /home/XXXX/www/www/includes/menu.inc(2794): menu_router_build()

#13 /home/XXXX/www/www/includes/menu.inc(468): menu_rebuild()

#14 /home/XXXX/www/www/includes/menu.inc(1779): menu_get_item()

#15 /home/XXXX/www/www/includes/menu.inc(1794): menu_get_custom_theme(TRUE)

#16 /home/XXXX/www/www/includes/common.inc(5402): menu_set_custom_theme()

#17 /home/XXXX/www/www/includes/bootstrap.inc(2602): _drupal_bootstrap_full()

#18 /home/XXXX/www/www/index.php(20): drupal_bootstrap(7)

#19 {main}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: Based on new stack trace it's coming from `home/XXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/civicrm/civicrm_handler_filter_pseudo_constant.inc` line 45, which is this:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/e22d89a50108a2b4da99e971d0fdcdd656edd56c/modules/views/civicrm/civicrm_handler_filter_pseudo_constant.inc#L45

`$this->_pseudo_constant = call_user_func_array($this->definition['pseudo class'] . "::" . $this->definition['pseudo method'], $pseudo_args);`

So that needs updating in the https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal repo. It's not clear how easy that would be to do. I would log a ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/new. (Update: Done: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/175)

---

It's usually from an extension. You can grep your extensions folder for `CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::pcpStatus` and see what comes up. If you're on the latest version of it, then you can file an issue on their extension repo.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Demerit. I searched through the extensions folder (sites/default/files/civicrm/ext), but didn't find that string. Found some others with CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::, but not with pcpStatus.

Comment: Then you can either grep the whole install (possibly it's in a drupal module?), or edit CRM_Core_Error::deprecatedFunctionWarning() so that it outputs a full backtrace in ConfigAndLog by adding `CRM_Core_Error::backtrace('backTrace', TRUE);` near the top of the function, which will tell you where it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Demerit. I was finally able to figure out how to do this - I think. So this is what the log has for me: 

Mar 01 12:29:58  [warning] Deprecated function CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::pcpStatus, use Function pcpStatus will be removed.
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)

What can I do about that?

Comment: That looks like the same message you had in your original post. If you added the backtrace line there should be a lot more in the log. Did you try grep'ing the whole install?

Comment: I did try searching the whole Civi install and did not come up with that full string. Same with the Drupal modules folder. What is new in this log entry is [civi.tag] => deprecated. Maybe I did not add the backtrace line correctly. I inserted it in modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php at line 309 and can confirm that is is there.

Comment: It would be around line 1035, inside the deprecatedFunctionWarning() function.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Made that change and there is more detailed output, but I can't share it here due to character limits...

Comment: You can edit the original post - where it has links for "Share Edit Follow Close Flag"

Comment: I have added the output to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Great! That solves it. I've updated answer. It also explains why grep didn't work - since the code to make the function call uses generic variables for the function name.

Comment: Thanks Demerit. I do not have an account at https://lab.civicrm.org, nor do I feel qualified to log a ticket appropriately. I would be very grateful if you or someone who knows what they are doing would please do that.

Comment: Ok have created https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/175

Comment: Many thanks for all your help!